# Methods in custom LinkedList

Tags: c#, linked-list

I have a custom LinkedList here (using VS2013):

LinkedList.cs:

```
class LinkedList
{
    public int Count { get; set; }

    public Node Head { get; private set; }

    public LinkedList()
    {
        head = null;    // creates an empty linked list
        count = 0;
    }

    public void AddFront(int n)
    {
        Node newNode = new Node(n);
        newNode.Link = head;
        head = newNode;
        count++;
    }

    public void DeleteFront()
    {
        if (count > 0)
        {
            Node temp = head;
            head = temp.Link;
            temp = null;
            count--;
        }
    }
}
```

And I'm trying to add a custom method into it, called AddMusicCDToFront(MusicCD cd).
I already have my MusicCD.cs class (which has all the basic things, as well as a constructor):

```
public class MusicCD
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string SingerName{ get; set; }

    public string AlbumName { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to add in a method called AddMusicCDToFront(MusicCD cd) to the LinkedList class like so:

```
public void AddMusicCDToFront(MusicCD cd)
{
    Node music = new Node(300);
    music.Link = cd;
}
```

VS2013 throws this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'MusicCD' to 'Node'

I have a feeling the Node shouldn't be done that way...but I just can't quite place my head on why.
Here's the Node.cs:

```
class Node
{
    public int Data{ get; set; }

    internal Node Link { get; set; }
}
```

Also how do I traverse a Linked List and print out the data of each node?

Comment: You're using the `Link` property as **both** the data container and the reference to the next node. You should use two properties.

Comment: Am I supposed to use Data and Link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't you rather do something like:

```
public void AddMusicCDToFront(MusicCD cd)
{
    Node newNode = new Node(cd);
    newNode.Link = head;
    head = newNode;
    count++;
}
```

Maybe put the code of the `Node` class also?

If you want to change the Node class to store MusicCD objects, then change the int to MusicCD

```
class Node
{
    private MusicCD data;

    public MusicCD Data
    {
        get { return data; }
        set { data = value; }
    }
    private Node link;

    internal Node Link
    {
        get { return link; }
        set { link = value; }
    }

    public Node(MusicCD d)
    {
        this.data = d;
    }
}
```

There is a more reusable way to do this with generics or inheritance but that's going to take some reading on your part.

Comment: I have added my Node.cs. Unfortunately this one that you posted gave an error:

`The best overloaded method match for 'Node.Node(int)' has some invalid arguments 45 28`

Comment: Are you going to be storing int objects and MusicCD objects in the same linked list?  You're probably wanting just MusicCD objects in which case change `int data` to MusicCD data.  I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
How do I traverse a Linked List? Do I use a for loop and `Console.Write`?

Comment: Yea, print out the head node. Then use a while loop for the rest.

Comment: Thank you. I will set this as the answer.